# Why is the isinstance() function not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, boolean, isinstance

For example:

```
def test(arg = False):
    return arg, type(arg), isinstance(arg, int)

print(test())
```

will result in:

```
False, <class: 'bool', True>
```

The `arg` variable is `False` which is obviously a `boolean`. The `type()` function got it right but why does the `isinstance()` function says that `arg` is an `int`? Is this a bug?

**NOTE:** I'm using Python 3.8.5

Comment: Because `issubclass(bool, int)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `bool` objects are `int` objects, **in other words**:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

Or, put it another way:

```
>>> bool.mro()
[<class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: @TonyStark, use `type()` instead of `isinstance()` if you're testing for a specific type, i.e. without considering inheritance

Comment: @Michael Ruth Thanks!